# How to use Bootstrap when loading a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to load a bootstrap into a Rails application but it doesn't work, it loads like common HTML. This is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'mini_backtrace'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.18.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My apliccation.html.erb file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    ...
</body>

</html>
```

application.json is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.css.scss is:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; 
@import "bootstrap";
```

On railstutorial.org it creates a new custom.css.scss application and it has a application.css, not sass, file but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You're misspelling "application" as "apliccation". Check to see you're using the right spelling in your application.

Comment: It's a bit easier to load bootstrap from a CDN than to do it this way.

Comment: That file should not be called `application.json`.  It should  be called `application.js`  Application.json won't be included in the javascript loaded into the page.  Where is that file located in your app, like the exact path? Can you check that spelling in your app?